# Classification of articles fetched from the web as describing stock (trending) increase or decrease

Tags: dataset

I'm building an AI that works with natural language processing integrated in my school project application (an app dedicated to traders). I'm wondering what set of word is used most to express negativity (or positivity) in stock market? If a certain stock is decreasing in value (or increasing) what words are most likely to be appear on the press?

---

**Ultimate Goal**: Classifying an article fetched from the web as describing stock increase or decrease.

---

Are there any public free data sets tackling this subject?

Else, is there a data set that classifies sentences as trending or not trending?

Any suggestion, help or even collaboration would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a deep learning network to generate **sentiment analysis**. Pretrained models can be found which have been trained using vectorized word lists which are commonly associated with positivity and negativity. However, these may not generalize well to your specific use case.

Due to the historic nature of stocks you can easily compile your own database from online sources. For example, you can construct instances in your dataset as follows. Tokenize all the words found in articles pertaining to Google for February 5th 2001, then the target label can be the stock value for February 7th 2001. You can choose the time lag as you please. If you do this for a large amount of instances, your dataset should be able to contain some notion of what words found in articles will cause a stock price to rise or lower.